# Duplicate data when joining sql pivot table with columns from other tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to combine columns from three tables with a Pivot table and it's giving me duplicate rows with the pivot values being off and I can't find a way to work around it.

Here is the query I have so far:

```
SELECT 
  r.resourceId AS ResourceID, 
  r.resourceName AS ResourceName,
  p.projectId As ProjectId,
  p.projectNumber AS ProjectNumber,
  p.projectName AS ProjectName,
  p.projectSystem AS ProjectSystem,
  p.projectManager AS ProjectManager,
  a.[May 2014],
  a.[June 2014]

FROM 
  Projects p, Resources r 
JOIN (
  SELECT * FROM allocation a
    PIVOT (SUM(allocationValue) FOR AllocationMonth IN ([May 2014], [June 2014])) PVT
) a ON (r.resourceId = a.resourceId) ORDER BY resourceId
```

I know the reason is because one resource may be allocated to several projects and this query doesn't make that distinction, my question is how do I make it so that it pivots based on the resourceId as well as the projectId?

When I edit the last line to "ON (r.resourceId = a.resourceId AND p.projectId = a.projectId) ORDER BY resourceId" I get this error "The multi-part identifier "p.projectId" could not be bound."

I'm new to SQL so any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT 
r.resourceId AS ResourceID, 
r.resourceName AS ResourceName,
p.projectId As ProjectId,
p.projectNumber AS ProjectNumber,
p.projectName AS ProjectName,
p.projectSystem AS ProjectSystem,
p.projectManager AS ProjectManager,
a.[May 2014],
a.[June 2014]

FROM 
  Projects p, Resources r 
JOIN (
  SELECT * FROM allocation a
    PIVOT (SUM(allocationValue) FOR AllocationMonth IN ([May 2014], [June 2014])) PVT
) a ON (r.resourceId = a.resourceId) ORDER BY resourceId
where p.projectId = a.projectId
```

Comment: That worked!  Just had to put the "ORDER BY" at the end.  Thanks a ton!